# How to save multiple data using shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making an app, wherein in this activity, I am trying to take data from the user and save it using shared preference.But the app crashes on click of the sign up button.
[image]

Here is the SignUpActivity.java file -

```
package com.example.abinas.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText e3;
private EditText e4;
private EditText e5;
private EditText e6;
private Button b2;
private RadioGroup rg;
private RadioButton rb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioroup);
    e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    e5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    e6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    int selected_id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(selected_id);
}

public void onButtonClick(View view){

    final SharedPreferences pref;
    pref = getSharedPreferences("user_info",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("gender",rb.getText().toString());
    edit.putString("username",e4.getText().toString());
    edit.putString("name",e3.getText().toString());
    edit.putString("password",e5.getText().toString());
    edit.putInt("phone",Integer.parseInt(e6.getText().toString()));
    edit.apply();
    edit.commit();
    //b2.setText("SAVED");
    //b2.setClickable(false);
}
}
```

what changes should be done, to successfully save the data?

Comment: Please share your stack trace

Comment: You are wrong place. First look into crash log and then fix your problem by finding why it is crashing

Comment: please share the logcat report or crash report?

Comment: create an object and then convert it to json and save it as string , then when you want to get the data , convert the json String to object --> you will get the data without any problem

Comment: seems like there was an error, when the string from the Radio Button was being stored in the shared preference.there was th following error in logcat.

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference

.on commenting out that line , the app worked.
How can this be solved????

Answer (score 4):

```
 1. Create a public class SharedPreference Manager and a class Keystring that will contain multiple data like name, user name , password, phone number.
 2. Then create object of this class anywhere in the project
 3. Get and put value easily anywhere
```

### SharedPreferenceManager

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;


public class SharedPreferenceManager {

    protected Context mContext;


    protected SharedPreferences mSettings;
    protected Editor mEditor;

    public SharedPreferenceManager(Context ctx, String prefFileName) {
        mContext = ctx;

        mSettings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(prefFileName,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditor = mSettings.edit();
    }

    /***
     * Set a value for the key
     ****/
    public void setValue(String key, String value) {
        mEditor.putString(key, value);
        mEditor.commit();
    }


    /***
     * Set a value for the key
     ****/
    public void setValue(String key, int value) {
        mEditor.putInt(key, value);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    /***
     * Set a value for the key
     ****/
    public void setValue(String key, double value) {
        setValue(key, Double.toString(value));
    }

    /***
     * Set a value for the key
     ****/
    public void setValue(String key, long value) {
        mEditor.putLong(key, value);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    /****
     * Gets the value from the settings stored natively on the device.
     *
     * @param defaultValue Default value for the key, if one is not found.
     **/
    public String getValue(String key, String defaultValue) {
        return mSettings.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public int getIntValue(String key, int defaultValue) {
        return mSettings.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public long getLongValue(String key, long defaultValue) {
        return mSettings.getLong(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /****
     * Gets the value from the preferences stored natively on the device.
     *
     * @param defValue Default value for the key, if one is not found.
     **/
    public boolean getValue(String key, boolean defValue) {
        return mSettings.getBoolean(key, defValue);
    }

    public void setValue(String key, boolean value) {
        mEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
        mEditor.commit();
    }



    /**
     * Clear all the preferences store in this {@link android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor}
     */
    public boolean clear() {
        try {
            mEditor.clear().commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes preference entry for the given key.
     *
     * @param key
     */
    public void removeValue(String key) {
        if (mEditor != null) {
            mEditor.remove(key).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

### KeyString

```
public class KeyString {
public static String PREFERENCE_NAME ="APP_PREF";
public static String NAME="NAME";
public static String USER_NAME="USER_NAME";
public static String PHONE_NUMBER="PHONE_NUMBER";
public static String PASSWORD="PASSWORD";
public static String USER_ID="USER_ID";
```

}

### In any activity anywhere on project##

```
private SharedPreferenceManager preferenceManager=new new SharedPreferenceManager(context, KeyString.PREFERENCE_NAME);
```

### Now set some value

```
preferenceManager.setValue(KeyString.PHONE_NUMBER,"01714262873");
```

### get data from prefs

```
String phoneNumber=preferenceManager.getValue(KeyString.PHONE_NUMBER,""); //default value ""
```

By this method you can set and get your desired number of variable and value. just add in the keyString and play.happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

You code has both `edit.apply()`, and `edit.commit()`. Use only one of them.